# query params for multiple drown downs in ember-cli application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, query-string

I have three models

> country,
>   city, mall

The route would look like

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model: (params) ->
   Ember.RSVP.hash country: @store.find('country', params);
});
```

The template would look like

```
{{view "select" 
  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
  content=model.country
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  value=selectedCountry
  prompt="Country"
  }}
  {{view "select" 
  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
  content=currentCities
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  value=selectedCity
  prompt=City
  }} 
  {{view "select" 
  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
  content=currentMalls
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  value=value
  prompt=Mall
  }}
```

city and mall dropdown generate dynamically based on country and city selection respectively

In my controller i have

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 queryParams: ['selectedCountry', 'selectedCity']
 selectedCountry: null,
 seletedCity: null,
 currentCities: null,
 currentMalls: null,

selectedCountryChanged: function() {
  this.set('currentCities', this.store.find('city');    
}.observes('selectedCountry')
selectedCityChanged: function() {
this.set('currentMalls', this.store.find('mall'));    
}.observes('selectedCity')
});
```

query param works properly for first drop down but i dont get correct value for second dropdown suppose i select country as united states the resource called is

> res/v1.0/countries/unitedstates

when i select the city, the resource looks like

> res/v1.0/countries/unitedstates/cities/chicago

when i copy the url with those selected values.. the query param

> selectedCountry=unitedstates&selectedCity=undefined

can you please suggest me a solution for the above. Basically city should also load before i assign query param to it.. but city loading would depend on country query param

Comment: Please, post more info on problem: how exactly your template looks like (all 3 selects), how it all works now and how it should work.

Comment: What is a "drown down"?

Comment: @torazaburo it's dropdown (<select />), I guess

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added how the template will look

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by just changing your store.find expressions and assuming a straightforward api.

route:

```
model: function () {
  return this.store.find('country');
  // call looks like: api/countries
}
```

controller:

```
 selectedCountry: null,
 selectedCity: null, 
 selectedMall: null,

 currentCities: null,
 currentMalls: null,

 getCities: Ember.observer('selectedCountry',function(){
    var params = {country: this.get('selectedCountry')};
    this.set('currentCities', this.store.findQuery('city',params));
        // call looks like: api/cities?country=US
 }),
 getMalls: Ember.observer('selectedCity',function(){
    var params = {country: this.get('selectedCountry'), city: this.get('selectedCity')};
    this.set('currentMalls', this.store.findQuery('mall',params));
        // call looks like: api/malls?country=US&city=LA
 }),
```

I think the api for the list of countries doesn't require query params, whereas the dependent list of cities or malls would use query params.